# oracle query for no data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table A  with col1 ,col2  with  data as

```
col1  col2
-----------
1     x
2     x
3     x
1     y
2     y
3     y
4     y
1     z
2     z
```

I want output as:

```
col1  col2
-----------
1     x
2     x
3     x
4     x
1     y
2     y
3     y
4     y
1     z
2     z
3     z
4     z
```

Even if values are not there in col2 for max value in col1 i.e '4' query should display up to 4.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM YourTable) A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM YourTable) B
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the cartesian product of each possible combination of values in col1 and col2:

```
Select col1, col2 from 
(select distinct col1 from sourcetable) as t1
Cross join
(select distinct col2 from sourcetable) as t2
```